# How to initialize a const generic array?

Tags: generics, rust, const-generics

I am trying to learn more about const generics and how they can apply to some grid algorithms in any dimensions. Below is a snippet - how can I create an array of the size of a const generic parameter?

```
type Point<const N: usize> = [i32; N];

fn new_point<const N: usize>(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point<N> {
    [x, y]
}

fn main() {
    let point: Point<2> = new_point(1, 2);
    println!("Point: {:?}", point)
}
```

The above results in a compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
3 | fn new_point<const N: usize>(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point<N> {
  |                                                 -------- expected `[i32; N]` because of return type
4 |     [x, y]
  |     ^^^^^^ expected `N`, found `2_usize`
  |
  = note: expected array `[i32; N]`
             found array `[i32; 2]`
```

Note that I am not looking for a solution using `Vec<N>`. How can I initialize this generic array with some values?

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc1ed4a5f7d96f145188ba211d3b1839 ?

Comment: Well, your function is not generic over `N`. You always return `Point<2>` no matter the value of `N`. Why try to make it generic in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some ways to construct an array of arbitrary length.

- You can use [`std::array::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_fn.html) which will allow constructing an array of any size from a function computing its elements:

  ```rust
  /// Constructs an array with the first two elements being x and y.
  fn new_point<const N: usize>(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point<N> {
      std::array::from_fn(|i| {
          match i {
              0 => x,
              1 => y,
              _ => 0,
          }
      })
  }
  ```
- You can construct an array with copies of a single value:

  ```rust
  [0; N]

  // or
  [foo(); N]
  ```
- You can construct an array and then mutate it:

  ```rust
  fn new_point<const N: usize>(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point<N> {
      let mut array = [0; N];
      if N > 0 {
          array[0] = x;
      }
      if N > 1 {
          array[1] = y;
      }
      array
  }
  ```
- You can construct an array by `map`ping from another array (this used to be done as a workaround for lack of `from_fn()`):

  ```rust
  let mut i = 0;
  [(); N].map(|()| {
      i += 1;
      i
  }]
  ```
- You can construct an array by using `.try_into()` to convert a slice or vector; the conversion will fail if the slice or vector is not the correct length. See the list of [implementors of `TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html#implementors), and look for the ones that say `... for [T; N]`.

Comment: looks like `from_fn` is stable now?